# Sum of series:$ 1+(1+2+4)+(4+6+9)+(9+12+16)+.....+(361+380+400)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of series 
$$ 1+(1+2+4)+(4+6+9)+(9+12+16)+.....+(361+380+400)$$
I have the problem in finding the nth term of the series. Please suggest me the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{19}\left(n^2+n(n+1)+(n+1)^2\right) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{19}\left((n+1)^3-n^3\right)=20^3=\color{red}{8000}.$$

Comment: The demonstration is even shorter if you start from $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If the first term is term 0, then the nth term could be $$n\cdot n+n\cdot (n+1)+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your terms look something of the form:
$$a_0 = 1, a_1 = (1+2+4) = 1^2 + 1\cdot 2 + 2^2$$
$$a_2 = (4 + 6 + 9) = 2^2 + 2\cdot 3 + 3^2$$
$$a_{19} = (19^2 + 19\cdot 20 + 20^2)$$

$$\sum_{j=0}\big[j^2 + j(j+1) + (j+1)^2\big]$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series, $$ (1+2+4)+(4+6+9)+(9+12+16)+\cdots+ (361+380+400)$$
Here the **general term** , $a_i = i^2 + (i+1)(i) + (i+1)^2$

Now, with this you can find $\sum_{i=0}^{n=19} a_i = 7999$

But according to your question, $\sum_{i=0}^{n=19} a_i + 1$ is required.

$\therefore$ *The sum of the given sequence* is **8000**.